# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Martial Arts Stack Exchange](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Aikido forward roll with backpack](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/aikido-forward-roll-with-backpack)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Practical knife defense stance](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3095/practical-knife-defense-stance)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How much should the torso and shoulders rotate when throwing a powerful cross in Muay Thai?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-much-should-the-torso-and-shoulders-rotate-when-throwing-a-powerful-cross-in)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [In which situations in Muay Thai is the 'super man' punch used and why is it more effective than the normal 'cross punch'?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3113/in-which-situations-in-muay-thai-is-the-super-man-punch-used-and-why-is-it-mor)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Endurance vs. Technique in Boxing](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3126/endurance-vs-technique-in-boxing)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Best to learn for self defense: Wrestling, Boxing, or Jiu Jitsu](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/best-to-learn-for-self-defense-wrestling-boxing-or-jui-jitsu)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How harmful are kicks to the private parts in krav maga?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/how-harmful-are-kicks-to-the-private-parts-in-krav-maga)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Solo martial art learning](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/solo-martial-art-learning)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Which techniques are available in Muay Thai for blocking/avoiding a high roundhouse kick to the head?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3133/which-techniques-are-available-in-muay-thai-for-blocking-avoiding-a-high-roundho)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Good sources on using sticks for grappling/locks?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3109/good-sources-on-using-sticks-for-grappling-locks)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Comment: That's a rather disappointing result.

Answer (score 1):

It's considerably quieter here than on the other SE sites I'm with, but I think it's a useful resource. The signal-to-noise ratio tends to be pretty good and people are civil about their differences. There's a bit of silliness involved with people asking about fictional martial arts, or asking Shark vs. Gorilla sorts of questions of the efficacy of different styles, but overall, it's good.

Comment: What do you mean with 'silliness'?

Comment: @THelper:
Looking now, it seems that they've been moderated down to oblivion, but I remember questions alluding to One Piece (three sword technique with one in the mouth), Dragon Ball Z (something about increasing one's ki for a spirit bomb), and Bleach (April Fools, admittedly, but spoke of "improving one's bankai" and then made a few more references to the show).